# Meteor publication's this.ready doesn't trigger

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, meteor-publications

I combined two of my publications into a single one, as they were very similar. Both of them returned a set of cursor. I've rewritten them in low-level API, in order to make some control on data removing.

My problem is that, for a reason I totally ignore, the subscription `onReady` callback is never triggered. I've got other low-level pubsub in my app which publish data in a similar way and that works perfectly.

On the server, all my logs are correctly displayed, and no error is shown. The publication is runned correctly and the data are effectively sent to the client.
On the client, none of the `onReady` or `onError` callback is triggered.

**Publication :**

```
Meteor.publish("getTalkthread", function ( thread_id ) {
  unblock(this);

    console.log("start");

  let uids = tags = corrections = [],
            self = this;

    let posts_cursor = Modules.both.queryGet({
                type                : 'posts',
                method          : 'find',
                query               : { $or: [
                            { _id: thread_id },
                            { parent: thread_id }
                          ]
                        },
                projection  : { sort    : { _id: 1 },
                                                limit   : 50
                                            }
            });

  let posts_array = posts_cursor.fetch(),
      posts_ids = posts_array.map( e => ( e._id ) );

    //console.log("fetched posts", posts_array);

  let corrs_cursor = Modules.both.queryGet({
                type                : 'corrections',
                method          : 'find',
                query               : { talkId: { $in: posts_ids } },
                projection  : { sort    : { _id: 1 },
                                                limit   : 50
                                            }
            });

  let corrs_array = corrs_cursor.fetch();

    //console.log("fetched corrs", corrs_array);

  let posts_authors = posts_array.map( e => ( e.owner ) ),
      corrs_authors = corrs_array.map( e => ( e.owner ) );

  let users_ids = _.union( posts_authors, corrs_authors );

  let users_cursor = Modules.both.queryGet({
            type                : 'users',
            method          : 'find',
            query               : { _id: { $in: users_ids } },
            projection  : { sort        : { date: -1 },
                            limit       : 100,
                            fields  : USER_PROFILE_FIELDS_
                        }
        });

    //console.log("fetched users", users_cursor.fetch());

  let observers = {};

  observers.posts = posts_cursor.observeChanges({
        added       : ( id, fields )    => { console.log("post added " + id); self.added  ("posts", id, fields); },
        changed : ( id, fields )    => { console.log("post changed " + id); self.changed("posts", id, fields);  },
        removed : ( id )                    => {
            console.log("test");
      if ( id != thread_id ) {
                console.log(true);
        self.removed("posts removed " + id);
      }
    }
    });

    observers.users = users_cursor.observeChanges({
        added       : ( id, fields )    => { console.log("user added " + id); self.added  ("users", id, fields);    },
        changed : ( id, fields )    => { console.log("user changed " + id); },
        removed : ( id )                    => { console.log("user removed " + id); }
    });

  observers.corrs = corrs_cursor.observeChanges({
        added       : ( id, fields )    => { console.log("corr added " + id); self.added  ("corrections", id, fields);  },
        changed : ( id, fields )    => { console.log("corr changed " + id); self.changed("corrections", id, fields);    },
        removed : ( id )                    => { console.log("corr removed " + id); self.removed("corrections", id);                }
    });

    console.log("observers created");

    this.ready();

  self.onStop( () => {
        observers.posts.stop();
        observers.users.stop();
        observers.corrs.stop();
    });

    console.log("end");

});
```

**Subscription :**

```
      console.log("sub");
      self.subscribe("getTalkthread", id, self.rerun.get()), {
        onReady: function () {
          console.log("READY");
          if ( !Posts.findOne({ _id: id } )) {
            $("#404NotFound").show();
            $("#isoContent").hide();
          } else if ( Posts.findOne( id ) ) {
            $("#isoContent").show();
          }
          $("#spin").hide();
        },
        onError: function () {
          console.log("ERROR");
          $("#spin").hide();
          $("#404NotFound").show();
          $("#isoContent").hide();
        }
      };
```

The client page is correctly rendered, but the DOM manipulation are not triggered, forbidding the display of the content. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong here ?

Thanks you

**EDIT:**

I tried to return an array of the three cursors, and, for whatever reason, the problem is the same. However, I don't see why.

Comment: not sure what `unblock(this);` is. There are packages that allow you to do `this.unblock()` in publications if that's what you meant

Comment: not sure what the problem is. i'd test with a blank publication that just called `this.ready` and see if your callback gets called on the client. then slowly build up the publication.

Comment: And the naming of the variables with underscores hurts my eyes. Use camelCase in JS. This isn't Python

Comment: unblock(this); is from my personnal lib. As some projects don't have the unblock package in some stages, or when I'm calling a method from both the server and the client.

I did rebuild the whole pub, without a result. Then, I switched the subscribe to Arunoda's subsManager, and it magicaly started to work well... So the problem is solved, though I've no idea why, and I hate this :p

I use to use camelCase in most cases, but well, some projects have a different norm, so I comply to it in order to remain coherent.

Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I don't understand why, using Arunoda's SubsManager instead of the native Meteor.subscribe resolved the problem.